# how to Print arabic on ESC/POS printer

Tags: vb.net

i am using visual studio 2005 and i want to print Arabic on POS thermal printer. when i try to print it shows ????? in print

here is my code:

```
Public Sub GiftReceipt()
        Try
            Dim displayString As String
            Dim ESC As String = Chr(&H1B) + "a" + Chr(0)
            Dim ESC2 As String = Chr(&H1B) + "@"
            Dim ESC1 As String = Chr(&H1B) + "a" + Chr(1)
            Dim ESC4 As String = Chr(&H1B) + "a" + Chr(2)
            Dim ESC5 As String = Chr(&H1B) + "!" + Chr(17)
            Dim ESC6 As String = Chr(&H1B) + "!" + Chr(1)
            Dim ESC7 As String = Chr(&H1B) + "t%"
            Dim ESC8 As String = Chr(&H1B) + "?0"
            Dim ESC9 As String = Chr(&H1B) + "R" + Chr(17)


            displayString = vbNewLine
            displayString += ESC7 + "معطار" + ESC8 + vbNewLine


            displayString += vbNewLine
            Dim pd As New PrintDialog()
            pd.PrinterSettings = New PrinterSettings()
            pd.UseEXDialog = True
            Call DefaultPrinterName()


            RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(DefaultPrinterName, displayString)



        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.ToString())

        End Try


    End Sub
```

i have alredy tried to convert it to windows-1256, and also tried using many esc pos commands

Comment: That RawPrinterHelper library you are using is very unhelpful.  You need to send bytes to the printer, not a string.  Get those bytes from Encoding.GetBytes().  Which specific encoding you need is something you need to look up in the printer's programming manual.  If it is an Epson printer and write ESC t% then you use character set 37 which is Arabic code page 864.  So use Encoding.GetEncoding(864).

Comment: What can i use instead of `RawPrinterHelper` library